# Event doesn't exist & UnknownDependEncyexeption

Tags: events, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a scoreboard plugin that shows all information needed to play the game.
I have a line that shows your chat channel that you're talking in.
I've imported the `ChannelJoinEvent` from VentureChat and used it to get the channel name.

I've depended on the plugin, because that was what they said on the Bukkit forums, but it doesn't help the problem.

Here is my code:

```
import mineverse.Aust1n46.chat.api.events.ChannelJoinEvent;

@EventHandler
public void onChannelJoin(ChannelJoinEvent e) {
    ChatChannel channel = e.getChannel();
    s4 = o.getScore("Chat Channel: " + channel.getColor() + channel);
}
```

The class of the event is public and the plugin itself is imported in the plugin and also in the plugins folder in the server.

This is the error in the console:
https://pastebin.com/WLCxXHGg

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you also install the plugin "ProtocolLib"? (https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/protocollib)
In the posted log it says:
`Could not load 'plugins\VentureChat.jar' ... UnknownDependencyException: ProtocolLib`.
VentureChat seems to depend on ProtocolLib and is not loaded because ProtocolLib is missing.
You plugin fails to load afterwards because VentureChat was not loaded.